# Perform ngx-spinner unit testing

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using [ngx-spinner](https://github.com/Napster2210/ngx-spinner) on my component to show a loading indictor on the page on some remote call process. On my component I have the following code for ngx spinner:

```
<ngx-spinner [fullScreen]="true" type="ball-clip-rotate" size="medium" bdColor="rgba(51,51,51,0.1)" color="grey">
</ngx-spinner>
```

At the component on init while the page is loading I am showing the spinner like this:"

```
  constructor(
    private spinner: NgxSpinnerService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.spinner.show();
```

and after the I am making a remote call to the server and when that work is done I am hiding the spinner.

My goal is to create unit test for the same i.e when the page is loaded I need to make sure the spinner is showing on the page. In order to do that I wrote the following test case:

```
  it('should show loading indicator if the page is not loaded', () => {

    // pageLoaded should be try because the form will be loaded only when that is true based on ng if

    const element = getElementByTag('ngx-spinner');

    //What to write here?

  });
```

I am getting the element there in my test but I was not able to get the way to detect whether it is visible or not. I tried element.nativeElement.visible but it returned as null.

Answer (score 0):

I'll start off by saying that in the context of unit tests, a general rule of thumb is that each component should be tested in isolation. This means that you don't need to check that the spinner itself  is displayed, you only need to check to see if the show() method does get called. You can achieve this by spying on NgxSpinnerService :

```
  it('should show loading indicator if the page is not loaded', () => {
    const spinnerSpy = spyOn(TestBed.get(NgxSpinnerService), "show");
    expect(spinnerSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

With that being said, I noticed that when the spinner is displayed, a div is inserted within the `<ngx-spinner></ngx-spinner>` tag. Therefore you can then tell that it is on display if the length of its children is 1 :

```
  it('should show loading indicator if the page is not loaded', () => {
    // pageLoaded should be try because the form will be loaded only when that is true based on ng if
    const element = getElementByTag('ngx-spinner');
    //What to write here?
    expect(element.children.size).toBe(1);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing that, I notice one issue with unit testing ngx spinner, ngx spinner show from componenet ng on init is making spinner to come on ng test karma jasmine page, how to prevent that loader to appear on ng test page?

Comment: If you chose the former method of unit testing, you should be able to achieve your goal by mocking the show method : `spinnerSpy.and.returnValue(null)`. Put it before the expect call. You can also provide a mock for the `NgxSpinnerService` class.